# Configuration setting updates

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

How can I remove author name and datetime from drupal article from admin section? I have already tried admin content type configuration setting for the same, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the node type, in the "Display settings", there is a checkbox "Display author and date information", turn that off.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If solution @PraveenKumar suggested didn't work for you it means that your theme is not reading this settings but always displaying author's info. Find what theme your site uses and then find template file used for content type from which you want to remove author's info. Edit template file and remove rows which are displaying that info.